# Bloquear dias DatePickerFragment Android Studio

Tags: android, datepicker

preciso bloquear os dias do **DatePickerFragment**, os dias que podem ficar liberados para selecionar, será contado da data atual + 3 dias e os dias seguintes devem ficar bloqueados para selecionar, ou então dar uma mensagem se ele dia que o usuário selecionar foi maior que aquele período.
Tentei de várias formas mas não tive sucesso, segue abaixo onde carrego o  **DatePickerFragment**.
Obs: Estou usando **Android Studio**

*Botão para chamar a função*

```
btnDataEntrega = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDataEntrega);
    btnDataEntrega.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            exibirDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });
```

Função para exibir o **DatePicker**

```
 public void exibirDatePickerDialog() {
 DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();

    fragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(this, new DatePickerFragment.DatePickerFragmentListener() {

        public void updateChangedDate(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
            btnDataEntrega.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", dia)) + "/" + String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", mes + 1)) + "/" + String.valueOf(ano));
            dataAtual.set(ano, mes, dia);
        }
    }, dataAtual);

    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment");
}
```

Função que carrega o **DatePicker**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

static int dia;
static int mes;
static int ano;
static Context mContext;
static DatePickerFragmentListener mListener;

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    dia = dayOfMonth;
    mes = month;
    ano = year;

    mListener.updateChangedDate(dia, mes, ano);

}

public int show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String datePickerFragment) {

    return super.show(transaction, datePickerFragment);
}

public interface DatePickerFragmentListener {
    public void updateChangedDate(int dia, int mes, int ano);
}

public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Context context, DatePickerFragmentListener listener, Calendar dataAtual) {
    DatePickerFragment dialog = new DatePickerFragment();
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;

    diaAtual = dataAtual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dia = dataAtual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mes = dataAtual.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    ano = dataAtual.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", "Set Date");
    dialog.setArguments(args);


    return dialog;

}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(mContext, R.style.AppTheme_DialogTheme, mDataSetListener, ano, mes, dia);
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDataSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dia = dayOfMonth;
        mes = monthOfYear;
        ano = year;

        mListener.updateChangedDate(dia, mes, ano);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usar o método `add` para acrescentar os dias na data atual e o método `setMaxDate` para definição do *range*. Veja:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
dialog.setMaxDate(c);
```

Comment: Viana, não deu certo, estou postando o código completo da função e botão onde chamo o DatePicker